# I'm Receiving 'Invalid Type Int[Int]...', But It's Making No Sense

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, int

I need to complete a program where your array hold ten test scores. Then, you pass that array through a function that'll display the highest score of the ten.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;


   void showValue(int);//Function prototype
   int main()
 {
    const int results = 10;
    double tscores[results];
    int result;
    //Get the ten test scores from the user.
    cout << "Please enter the ten test scores." << endl;
    cin >> tscores[0];
    cin >> tscores[1];
    cin >> tscores[2];
    cin >> tscores[3];
    cin >> tscores[4];
    cin >> tscores[5];
    cin >> tscores[6];
    cin >> tscores[7];
    cin >> tscores[8];
    cin >> tscores[9];

    //Now, the program should pass the arry through a
    //function to find the highest test score.
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
      {
      if (result[0] > max)
            {
                 max = result[0];
            }
      }

 cout << "The highest score is " << max << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I got:

```
    Prog4r.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    Prog4r.cpp:37:16: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
    Prog4r.cpp:39:19: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
```

I just can't seem to fix the issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `result` is not an array.

Comment: Also you're storing the values as double values then calculating the max as an integer. Be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, you try and access an index from the variable named `result`, which is not an array.

```
if( result[0] > max )
{
    max = result[0];
}
```

A few things are wrong here,

> 1. You want to access the array variable named `tscores`.
> 2. You want to use the loop variable instead of 0.
> 3. Your variable `max` should be the same type as `tscores`.

```
double max = 0.0;

for( int i = 0; i < results; ++i )
{
    if ( tscores[i] > max )
    {
        max = tscores[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: Yes, change `max` to a double. Editted answer.  Also, your second answer should be a comment. :)